# How to embed button of Shoppy on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, java, html, wordpress, embed

Shoppy drops this SCRIPT for embedding produts on a button in HTML

```
<script src="https://shoppy.gg/api/embed.js"></script>
<button data-shoppy-product="PRODUCT ID">Pay</button>
```

How can I put this (SCRIPT SRC) metatag on my Wordpress? I have elemental plugin.
In the button edition of Wordpress you have the "custom embed script" so I can put that button data, but where can I set the script src?

Comment: Formatted code, removed unnecessary parts

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us. After you make a good attempt at doing this yourself and if you still have problems, you can update your question with details of the specific problem and what you have tried to dolve it, and include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we are able to help.